# What does 'let-off' mean in football (soccer)?

Tags: meaning-in-context, phrasal-verbs, terminology

What does 'let-off' mean in football (soccer

5' Another let-off for a QPR player - Wszolek hacks down Gunter as he skips down the right... foul, but no card for a hefty challenge.

Answer (score 2):

To **let someone off** often means to allow that person to get away with breaking rules without facing a punishment.  It derives from the notion of "letting someone *escape*," but has adapted itself to refer to evading any form of punishment, not just capture.

> The police **let her off** with a warning.

In this case, the writer hyphenates "let" and "off" to create a noun that represents the idea of getting off without punishment, which in this case means no card in the game of football.

Because the player was **let off** without a card, the writer calls it a **let-off**.